# Error deploying OLAP cube from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, olap, ssas

I've imported a OLAP cube which was created by one of my colleagues directly on SQL Server Management Studio.
So I import it in a Visual Studio project and then just make one little modification. I want to depoy it to a server. But I have a lot of errors.

The errors appear when I try to deploy my project, but not when I compile the project .

Did someone already have this problem? Can someone help me for this problem?

**Details of error log in visual studio development :

```
 
Error   76  Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'MARCHE NUM' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   77  Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Devises' et le nom 'Devises'.     0   0   
Error   78  Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'CODE NUM' de la dimension 'Devises' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   79  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   80  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   81  Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   82  Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'DEVISE STR' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   83  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   84  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   85  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   86  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   87  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   88  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   89  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   90  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   91  Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   92  Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     
Error   135 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'LIBELLE' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.       0   0   
Error   136 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   137 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   138 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   139 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   140 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   141 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Folio' et le nom 'Folio'.     0   0   
Error   142 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'SSECTION' de la dimension 'Folio' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   143 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. L'exception suivante s'est produite lors de l'utilisation de l'interface IDbConnection managée : ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu .     0   0   
Error   144 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. Une connexion n'a pas pu être établie à la source de données avec le DataSourceID, 'resultatMX', nom de 'resultat-msrsot'.       0   0   
Error   145 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Commo' et le nom 'Commo'.     0   0   
Error   146 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'COMMO NAME' de la dimension 'Commo' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   147 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   148 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Folio' et le nom 'Folio'.     0   0   
Error   149 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'LIBSECTION' de la dimension 'Folio' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   150 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   151 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   152 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   153 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. L'exception suivante s'est produite lors de l'utilisation de l'interface IDbConnection managée : ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu .     0   0   
Error   154 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. Une connexion n'a pas pu être établie à la source de données avec le DataSourceID, 'resultatMX', nom de 'resultat-msrsot'.       0   0   
Error   155 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'RefFamily' et le nom 'RefFamily'.     0   0   
Error   156 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'DATEJ' de la dimension 'RefFamily' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.       0   0   
Error   157 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   158 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   159 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   160 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   161 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'MATURITY DAY' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   162 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   163 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   164 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   165 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   166 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   167 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   168 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'REFERENCE' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.     0   0   
Error   169 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   170 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   171 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   172 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   173 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   174 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'DELIVERY TYPE' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.     0   0   
Error   175 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   176 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   177 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   178 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   179 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   180 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   181 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   182 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   183 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   184 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   185 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'DEVISE NUM' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   186 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. L'exception suivante s'est produite lors de l'utilisation de l'interface IDbConnection managée : ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu .     0   0   
Error   187 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. Une connexion n'a pas pu être établie à la source de données avec le DataSourceID, 'resultatMX', nom de 'resultat-msrsot'.       0   0   
Error   188 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Commo' et le nom 'Commo'.     0   0   
Error   189 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'DATEJ' de la dimension 'Commo' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.       0   0   
Error   190 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   191 Erreur interne : L'opération n'a pas abouti.        0   0   
Error   192 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Devises' et le nom 'Devises'.     0   0   
Error   193 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'INVERSERRIC' de la dimension 'Devises' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.       0   0   
Error   194 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Devises' et le nom 'Devises'.     0   0   
Error   195 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'MASTERCURRENCY' de la dimension 'Devises' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   196 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Folio' et le nom 'Folio'.     0   0   
Error   197 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'MARKET' de la dimension 'Folio' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   198 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Devises' et le nom 'Devises'.     0   0   
Error   199 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'REF COMMODITY' de la dimension 'Devises' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.     0   0   
Error   200 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. L'exception suivante s'est produite lors de l'utilisation de l'interface IDbConnection managée : ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu .     0   0   
Error   201 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. Une connexion n'a pas pu être établie à la source de données avec le DataSourceID, 'resultatMX', nom de 'resultat-msrsot'.       0   0   
Error   202 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Commo' et le nom 'Commo'.     0   0   
Error   203 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'SICOVAM' de la dimension 'Commo' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.     0   0   
Error   204 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Devises' et le nom 'Devises'.     0   0   
Error   205 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'CODE STR' de la dimension 'Devises' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   206 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Deals' et le nom 'Deals'.     0   0   
Error   207 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'DATE NEG' de la dimension 'Deals' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   208 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. L'exception suivante s'est produite lors de l'utilisation de l'interface IDbConnection managée : ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu .     0   0   
Error   209 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. Une connexion n'a pas pu être établie à la source de données avec le DataSourceID, 'resultatMX', nom de 'resultat-msrsot'.       0   0   
Error   210 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Deals' et le nom 'Deals'.     0   0   
Error   211 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'REFCON' de la dimension 'Deals' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   212 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   213 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'SICOVAM' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.       0   0   
Error   214 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. L'exception suivante s'est produite lors de l'utilisation de l'interface IDbConnection managée : ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu .     0   0   
Error   215 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. Une connexion n'a pas pu être établie à la source de données avec le DataSourceID, 'resultatMX', nom de 'resultat-msrsot'.       0   0   
Error   216 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Family' et le nom 'Family'.       0   0   
Error   217 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'FAMILY' de la dimension 'Family' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.     0   0   
Error   218 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   219 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'MODEL NAME' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   220 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Folio' et le nom 'Folio'.     0   0   
Error   221 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'FOLIO' de la dimension 'Folio' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.       0   0   
Error   222 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   223 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'UNIT TRADDING' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.     0   0   
Error   224 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Deals' et le nom 'Deals'.     0   0   
Error   225 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'CONTREPARTIE' de la dimension 'Deals' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   226 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   227 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'AFFECTATION STR' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.       0   0   
Error   228 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Positions' et le nom 'Positions'.     0   0   
Error   229 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'DATEJ' de la dimension 'Positions' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.       0   0   
Error   230 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   231 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'MATURITY DATE' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.     0   0   
Error   232 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Deals' et le nom 'Deals'.     0   0   
Error   233 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'STATUT' de la dimension 'Deals' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   234 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Deals' et le nom 'Deals'.     0   0   
Error   235 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'DATEJ' de la dimension 'Deals' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.       0   0   
Error   236 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Devises' et le nom 'Devises'.     0   0   
Error   237 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'MEASURE UNIT' de la dimension 'Devises' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   238 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Folio' et le nom 'Folio'.     0   0   
Error   239 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'ENTITE' de la dimension 'Folio' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   240 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Instruments' et le nom 'Instruments'.     0   0   
Error   241 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'MARCHE STR' de la dimension 'Instruments' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   242 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Folio' et le nom 'Folio'.     0   0   
Error   243 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'TYPE' de la dimension 'Folio' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   244 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Folio' et le nom 'Folio'.     0   0   
Error   245 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'SICOVAM' de la dimension 'Folio' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.     0   0   
Error   246 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. L'exception suivante s'est produite lors de l'utilisation de l'interface IDbConnection managée : ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu .     0   0   
Error   247 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. Une connexion n'a pas pu être établie à la source de données avec le DataSourceID, 'resultatMX', nom de 'resultat-msrsot'.       0   0   
Error   248 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Deals' et le nom 'Deals'.     0   0   
Error   249 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'AFFECTATION' de la dimension 'Deals' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.     0   0   
Error   250 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. L'exception suivante s'est produite lors de l'utilisation de l'interface IDbConnection managée : ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu .     0   0   
Error   251 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. Une connexion n'a pas pu être établie à la source de données avec le DataSourceID, 'resultatMX', nom de 'resultat-msrsot'.       0   0   
Error   252 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Deals' et le nom 'Deals'.     0   0   
Error   253 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'MVTIDENT FW' de la dimension 'Deals' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.     0   0   
Error   254 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. L'exception suivante s'est produite lors de l'utilisation de l'interface IDbConnection managée : ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu .     0   0   
Error   255 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. Une connexion n'a pas pu être établie à la source de données avec le DataSourceID, 'resultatMX', nom de 'resultat-msrsot'.       0   0   
Error   256 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'RefFamily' et le nom 'RefFamily'.     0   0   
Error   257 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'REF FAMILY' de la dimension 'RefFamily' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0   
Error   258 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Deals' et le nom 'Deals'.     0   0   
Error   259 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'DATE VAL' de la dimension 'Deals' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.        0   0   
Error   260 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. L'exception suivante s'est produite lors de l'utilisation de l'interface IDbConnection managée : ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu .     0   0   
Error   261 Erreurs dans le moteur relationnel de haut niveau. Une connexion n'a pas pu être établie à la source de données avec le DataSourceID, 'resultatMX', nom de 'resultat-msrsot'.       0   0   
Error   262 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de dimension portant l'ID 'Deals' et le nom 'Deals'.     0   0   
Error   263 Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de l'attribut 'SICOVAM FW' de la dimension 'Deals' de la base de données 'CubeCom'.      0   0****
```

Comment: It seems to be a connection error in 'resultatMX' have yo checked that all connectionstrings are still working after the import?

Comment: Hello,  yes I check the connectionstrings and there is no problem on it.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-12154: TNS: connection identifier specified could not be resolved

http://ora-12154.ora-code.com/

This sounds more like a Connectivity issue to me.  Did you try connecting from your local machine to resultatMX?